# Django 2.1: How to import models in a custom .py file?

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-import

I'm currently working on a Django project that has the following structure

```
django_project/
    django_app/
        views.py
        models.py
        urls.py
        src/
            myCustomFile.py
```

In this context, I would like to import the models in myCustomFile.py. 
Usually, to import models in other files I include the following line of code

```
from django_app.models import *
```

but apparently, I do not seem to work. I think that the problem could be due to the fact that myCustomFile.py is in a subfolder. For this reason, I also tried to move myCustomFile.py at the same level of models.py but also, in this case, I get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_app'
```

Do you have any suggestion to solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to run the Python file directly?

Comment: One usually defines a custom commands: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: You can set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, or run the Python file with as current directory the `django_project`, but both will not help, since you can not just import these models: very frequently this will fail. Normally you want to first load the Django context.

Comment: Create an empty `__init__.py` in your `src` directory and then `from django_app.src.myCustomFile import ...` ?

Comment: `from .models import ModalName` try this. from present directory it will import model

Comment: @KlausD. yes, I have a cronjob that executes the python script.

Comment: @JonClements I tried but It does not work.

Comment: You can't just call a sinple module from your Django project. For things that are run by cron there are management commands in Django.

Comment: I solved the problem by defining a custom command. Thank you again for your help!